# Domain Driven Design: Specification Question

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

currently the system I am working on is layered like this

- Web UI
- Application
- Domain
- Infrastructure

In which layer would I put the specification implementations? Infrastrucutre?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by specification implementation?

Comment: I mean the various implementations that than are injected into the domain layer.

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question if you are more specific.  Maybe a diagram?  What is the "Infrastructure" Layer.  What is running your "Application" Layer, J2EE or .Net?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Specifications** are part of the Domain Model.

This pattern is described in [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), and since this book deals explicitly with Domain Modeling, I think it's fair to say that it belongs in the Domain Layer.

Comment: Yes, the interface is located in the domain layer. But I am talking about the actual implementation that is being injected.

Comment: I would still put it in the Domain Model. However, it may use injected dependencies that are implemented elsewhere. See here for an example of what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264944/refactoring-domain-logic-that-accesses-repositories-in-a-legacy-system/1265055#1265055